# vector mergesort() nothing happens

Tags: c++

I am not too sure what I did wrong in this Mergesort algorithm I made.

my output I am receiving is
4 3 5 5 4 3 8 8 8

I am speculating my int mid value could be causing this but then again I don't think it really matters as I am being consistent in merger func.

````````````````````````````````````````
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

void merger(vector<int> &arr, int beg, int end) {

    vector<int> temp;
    int mid = (beg + end-1) / 2;
    int right=mid+1;
    int left = beg;
    while (left <= mid && right <= end) {
        if (arr[left] <= arr[right]) {
            temp.push_back(arr[left++]);
        }
        else temp.push_back(arr[right++]);
    }
    if(left<mid){
    while (left <= mid) {
        temp.push_back(arr[left++]);
    }
    }
    else{
    while (right <= end) {
        temp.push_back(arr[right++]);
    }
    }

    int j = 0;
    for (auto x : temp) {
        arr[j++] = x;
    }
   // temp.clear();

}


void mergesort(vector<int> &arr, int beg, int end) {
    //base case
    if (beg >= end)return;
    //make mid
    int mid = (beg+end-1) / 2;
    mergesort(arr, beg, mid);
    mergesort(arr, mid+1, end);
    merger(arr, beg, end);
}



int main() {

    vector<int> arr1 = { 7,5,2,4,10,5,4,3,8 };

    mergesort(arr1, 0, arr1.size()-1);

    for (auto x : arr1) {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Your functions work on vector copies (parameters placed in local storage). Learn about references in C++.

Answer (score 0):

In `merger`, the index variable `j` needs to start at `beg` because the elements you copy into `temp` start with `arr[beg]`. Change the declaration to

```
int j = beg;
```

right before you loop to copy the sorted `temp` array back into `arr`.